# Change stream not published when data is edited with MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb-compass, changestream

As the title suggest, when I make changes to data using MongoDB compass, the changes are not being published in the change stream. I have a Node.js service which listens to the change stream.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Changes were not published to stream when editing data in Robo3T. I can see changes in Mongo change stream when data is being edited via Spring Boot application.

The issue got fixed after adding replace operation type in watch list.

```
collection.watch(singletonList(Aggregates.match(Filters.in("operationType", asList("update", "insert","**replace**")))))
```